# Error in middleware: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined

Tags: express, middleware, mern

I am stuck in this problem wherein the console returns an unexpected error code whenever I try to intentionally fail the postman request. The expected results are somehow like this:
[image: Expected error message]

but instead, it shows a RangeError something like this:
[image: Unexpected error message]
Here is the code for my server.js:

```
dotenv.config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const app = express();

connectDB();


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running...");
});

app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(404);
  next(error);
});


app.use((err, req, res, next) =>{
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.StatusCode;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack,
  })
});


app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`.cyan.underline)
);
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running...");
});

app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(404);
  next(error);
});


app.use((err, req, res, next) =>{
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? res.StatusCode : 500;
    res.status(statusCode);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack,
    })
  });


app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`.cyan.underline)
);
```

And here is my productRoutes.js file:

```
const router = express.Router();


export default router;

router.get("/", asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});

    res.json(products);
  }));
router.get("/:id", asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    if(product){
        res.json(product);
    }
    else{
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error('Product not found');
    }
  }));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The error caused by a typo but I would like to explain to the author the meaning of the error and how to debug*

---

You can see in the error message

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
```

your server sends a response to the client with the status `undefined`. It is not a valid status code. See HTTP valid status code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

You can locate the block where the error occurs when you set the `statusCode` for the response:

```
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? res.StatusCode : 500;
  res.status(statusCode);
```

the name of the property is case-sensitive. `res.statusCode` has value but `res.StatusCode` is `undefined`. It should be:

```
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? res.statusCode : 500;
  res.status(statusCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please change this one line and try?

```
const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? res.StatusCode : 500;
```

Comment: sorry to ask, but what would I change it into? thanks!

Comment: update your this line. I have already  changed the line.

Comment: it worked when doing {{URL}}/api/'invalid_address' but it now yields the same error for {{URL}}/api/products/'invalid_id'.

Comment: have you also changed this line in `{{URL}}/api/products/'invalid_id`

Comment: sorry but I don't know what to change. I only changed one line so farr

Comment: can you post your controller function for `{{URL}}/api/products/'invalid_id`?

Comment: I edited my post and placed the server.js file and productRoutes.js file, thank you!

Comment: everywhere, you are using `const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.StatusCode;` replace it with `const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? res.StatusCode : 500;

`